# what is the difference between [[],[],...] and [(),(),...]

Tags: python

what is the diffence between this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

and this:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

or is is the same? if not, when should I use the one or the other?

Comment: The answer is on the title of the duplicated question.

Comment: The first is a list of lists, the second is a list of tuples.